# PointerLock API and Three.js

Tags: three.js

Hello I'm playing with Three.js PointerLock API example.

http://mrdoob.github.com/three.js/examples/misc_controls_pointerlock.html

In example it uses pitch and yaw dynamics, but only X is translated. 
I other words, camera is standing on ground, not letting me fly.

I tried rotating pitchObject Y and with LookAt() but in both case they act weird. maybe I should try other technique then pith and yaw for fly controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further research should be done on Pitch and Yaw technique flight dynamics.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flight_dynamics

Just added another variable **Y** to controls but instead of trying to add it pitch. I just made Yaw translate with **X**